# Vue application not showing data that is in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a Vue.js application which uses Vue-Router and Vuex. On one page a user updates their email address and I want them to relogin so I clear things first by doing a logout then I input the message into Vuex then push them to the login page/view.

If I use the Vue Chrome plugin I see the state is updated in the correct order and the proper data is there, ie no user data exists but my message exists

**Page I update email from**

This is in the response of the api call once I confirm the email update was successful.

```
this.$store.dispatch('logout')
this.$store.commit('loginInfo', 'Email updated, please login again.')
return this.$router.push('/login')
```

**Store/state file**

Excuse the lack of full file but it's not needed here just the below

```
// state
error: {
      registerErrorMessage: '',
      loginErrorMessage: '',
      loginInfoMessage: '',
      resetError: ''
},

// mutations
loginInfo(state, message) {
      state.error.loginInfoMessage = message
},
```

**Login.vue**

```
// Template
<div v-if="infoMessage" class="alert alert-info">
    {{ infoMessage }}
</div>

// Script
computed: {
    infoMessage() {
        return this.$store.getters.loginInfo
    }
}
```

Currently what happens is that it logs out the user, adds the message to Vuex and pushes them to login view without displaying the message

Comment: Up top you said `loginInfo` is a mutation. At the bottom in the component you're calling a getter. Did you actually create a getter for `loginInfo`?

Comment: @Arc good catch, that might be it, I'll give that a shot soon